# Contains query on Long values

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, criteria, spring-data-mongodb

I have a criteria that checks if the database value is equal to my parameter:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
...
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("number").is(parameterNumber);
```

Is it possible to make a criteria check if the database value `contains` my parameter number, knowing that my database value is a `Long` value?